# How to show x-axis dotted labels on y-axis for multiple column chart in hightchart js

Tags: javascript, highcharts

Can we show x-axis label names **year to date sales** and OKR for sales on y-axis for multiple column chart using highchart.
I am using this script

```
chart = Highcharts.chart('chart-container_'+nextChartId, {
            chart: {
                spacingTop: 3,
                spacingRight: 0,
                spacingBottom: 3,
                spacingLeft: 0,
                type: chartType, 
                inverted: hasSwitchChart
            },
            title: {
                text: resData.name, 
            },
             
            yAxis: {
                title: {
                    text: yAxisName
                },
                
            }, 
            xAxis: {
                categories: chartData,
                type: 'datetime',
                //reversed: true 
                title: {
                    text: xAxisName
                },
                   
            },
            plotOptions: {
                series: {
                            borderWidth: 0,
                            dataLabels: {
                                enabled: hasShowDataValue,
                                format: '{point.y}'
                        }
                }
            },
            series: chartSeriesData 
        });
```

Please see attachment!

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/js2t3hn9/3/

Please guide me.
Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see that you want to place legend items in place of the y-axis title. To do that, you can rotate and dynamically position the legend, for example in `render` event.

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {
  chart: {
    ...,
    events: {
      render: function() {
        const chart = this;
        chart.legend.group.attr({
          rotation: -90,
          translateX: 0,
          translateY: chart.yAxis[0].height / 2 + chart.legend.legendWidth / 2 + chart.plotTop
        });
      }
    }
  },
  legend: {
    enabled: true,
    align: 'left',
    verticalAlign: 'middle',
    floating: true
  },
  ...
});
```

---

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/fwmoyjxs/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.SVGElement#attr

Comment: Great Thanks let me check

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76387456/when-hover-on-column-bar-the-tooltip-is-not-showing-different-colors-for-multipl

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76604461/when-highchart-has-pagination-can-we-export-multiple-pages-of-highchart