# When hover on column bar the tooltip is not showing different colors for multiple columns in highchart

Tags: javascript, highcharts

When hover on column bar the tooltip should show two colors for **OKR for the year** and **Year to date** but it is showing same colors.
I am using this script.

```
tooltip: { 
                formatter: function() {  
                      
                    let xAxisValue = this.point.name;  
                    let yAxisValue = this.y;
                    let xAxisName = this.series.name;
                    
                    if(hasMultipleCols){
 
                        if(typeof chartArrayData[1] != 'undefined') {
 
                            yAxisValue =  chartArrayData[1].data[this.point.index]; // this.point.name == undefined ? this.point.y : this.point.name
                            xAxisValue =  chartArrayData[0].data[this.point.index];
                            xAxisName  =  chartArrayData[0].name;
                            yAxisName =   chartArrayData[1].name;
                        }
                         
                     }
                     return `<span style="color:${this.color}">●</span> ${yAxisName }: <b>${ yAxisValue}</b><br/><span style="color:${this.color}">●</span> ${xAxisName}: <b>${xAxisValue }</b>`;
                     
                },  
            }
```

Please attachment

[image]
Please guide me.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to enable the `shared` option for tooltip:

```
tooltip: {
  shared: true
}
```

However, if you want to keep your custom format, you can use the below formatter function:

```
  tooltip: {
    formatter: function() {
      const options = this;
      const allSeries = options.series.chart.series;
      let result = `<span style="color:${this.color}">●</span> ${options.series.name}: <b>${options.y}</b>`;

      allSeries.forEach(series => {
        if (series !== options.series) {
          const point = series.points.find(p => p.x === options.point.x);

          if (point) {
            result += `<br/><span style="color:${series.color}">●</span> ${series.name}: <b>${point.y}</b>`;
          }
        }
      });

      return result;
    }
  }
```

---

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/tf6jc5op/

**API Reference:**

https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/tooltip.formatter

https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/tooltip.shared

Comment: Why it gives error on multiple columns chart on this line  <b>${series.points[options.x].y}</b>.
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'y')
Before add this script values were showing.

Comment: I have debug that if two or more columns series.points[options.x] it give undefined. How can we get value.

Comment: Please check jsfiddle 
http://jsfiddle.net/0zr5746n/3/

Comment: For single column chart we need to show both values of y-axis and x-axis on tooltip. Currently in example it is showing one label with value.

Comment: This is single column chart example. It should show both staff and year to date sum label with values on tooltip.
http://jsfiddle.net/t9z7bs2q/

Comment: Hi @Raheel Aslam, Yes, you are right, I've improved the example. Please check: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/tf6jc5op/

Comment: Thank you @ppotaczek it is working fine. Please can you check the single column chart jsfiddle.

Comment: Sure, the code from the below example should work in both cases: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/3en0a9sr/

Comment: The year to date sum label and value should show on chart tooltip. 
Y-axis and X-axis label should on hover.  You can see y-axis label in this example
http://jsfiddle.net/2qdwh5px/

Comment: Now please can you check my updated jsfiddle. It is showing correct but one issue here.
the year to date sum label should be dynamic i added static.
http://jsfiddle.net/2qdwh5px/3/

Comment: So you want to show y-axis title? If so, use: `this.series.yAxis.axisTitle.textStr` Example: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/w37byn59/

Answer (score 0):

Change the color to a static variable, if the color is still the same with bar,
maybe you should check the `colorByPoint` property. if it's `true`, the color of the tooltip is set to the color of the point.

**the two `this.color` target to the same point, so change the second on to another's color.**

Plan 1: **add a `shared: true` property** to share the info between bars.

like this

```js
  tooltip: {
    formatter: function () {
    // something your code here.
      let secondColor = this.points && this.points.length > 1 ? this.points[1].color : this.color;
      return `<span style="color:${this.color}">●</span> yAxisName1: <b>yAxisName12</b><br/><span style="color:${secondColor}">●</span> xAxisName1: <b>xAxisName2</b>`
    },
    shared: true
  },
```

Plan 2: get color by:

`this.point.series.xAxis.series[1].color`

Comment: It is not working but bar has two different color why tooltip is same ?
 if (this.series.options.colorByPoint) {
            tooltipColor = this.color; // Set tooltip color based on the color of the point
          }

Comment: update my answer please check the newest

Comment: It still showing this #544fc5  color.

Comment: When shared: true it gives error
dashboard_apis.js?version=220042:4680 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'name')

Comment: Why it is not working when make true
let xAxisValue = this.point.name;  
     let yAxisValue = this.y;
     let xAxisName = this.series.name;

Comment: I think issue with these can you check please. 
let xAxisValue = this.point.name;  
     let yAxisValue = this.y;
     let xAxisName = this.series.name;
     
     if(hasMultipleCols){
 
      if(typeof chartArrayData[1] != 'undefined') {
 
       yAxisValue =  chartArrayData[1].data[this.point.index]; // this.point.name == undefined ? this.point.y : this.point.name
       xAxisValue =  chartArrayData[0].data[this.point.index];
       xAxisName  =  chartArrayData[0].name;
       yAxisName =   chartArrayData[1].name;
      }
       
      }

Comment: need to change the way to get `name`, check the [doc](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/tooltip.formatter)

Comment: maybe you can fix the color error first and add other info step by step. the `this.point.name` is not work in `shared` mode, replace by `this.points[i].point`, `i` is current point's index.

Comment: Ok let me first color error fix it.

Comment: The color has been changed but tooltip is not working properly.

Comment: Is there any way to do without shared: true because our existing functionality will disturb ? please.

Comment: Are you doing ?

Comment: yeah, try `this.point.series.xAxis.series[1].color`

Comment: thanks Can you update this jsfiddle ?
http://jsfiddle.net/0zr5746n/3/