# When highchart has pagination can we export multiple pages of highchart

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I have chart which has pagination and data is coming from server side. I am export the one image of highchart using SVG it is working fine for one page but problem, is it possible to export multiple pages when chart has pagination.

Is it possible to download the chart without render chart? I have options data from API.

I am using this script

```
$("body").on('click','.download-chart-btn', function() {
        html2canvas($(this).closest('.grid-stack-item-content').find('.dashboad_chart_render')[0]).then(function(canvas) {
                var imageUrl = canvas.toDataURL();
                var link = document.createElement('a');
                link.href = imageUrl;
                link.download = 'chart-image.png';
                link.click();
        });
    });
```

Please can you guide me.

[image]

Thanks

Comment: The chart data is coming from back-end in the form of pagination. When click the page number the data get from server and load the chart. How can do export multiple pages or what data need from back-end to export the multiple pages of chart.

Comment: Can we convert API data into directly into svg or image without render chart ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to directly create SVG without rendering an additional chart. Please check the `getSVG` chart's method with its `chartOptions` optional parameter:

> Additional chart options for the generated SVG representation. For
> collections like xAxis, yAxis or series, the additional options is
> either merged in to the original item of the same id, or to the first
> item if a common id is not found.

```
const chart = Highcharts.chart('container', {
  series: [{
    data: [...]
  }],
  ...
});

const svg = chart.getSVG({
  series: [{
    data: [...]
  }],
  ...
});
```

---

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/qk1t6wpj/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Chart#getSVG

Comment: i have series of data and comes from API. We have page numbers when click the page number call API and get data from server and pass to chart.
We want when click download button call all APIs of pages and download the charts.
For example if we have 3 pages and 3 pages APIs call and download the 3 charts at same time

Comment: I don't want to assign the container div.

Comment: Hi @Raheel Aslam, Yes, I know. I only presented the way how you can convert API data directly into SVG without rendering a chart. Here: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/bn1ea2cx/ you can find an example of downloading files.

Comment: Thanks one thing when download the chart the file type is undefined chart (66).undefined. How can fix this please

Comment: You just need to set the correct `type` and `filename`. Example: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/vmL2jdeu/